# First steps in Redux. How to add value to mapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm very new in Redux. I've built simple counter app and I want to add 'hide element' feature. So, I have to pass `props.show`. How exactly I can do it? Need I create new reducer or I can add this value to `mapStateToProps`?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const App = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <p>{props.count}</p>
            <button onClick={props.increment}>+</button>
            <button onClick={props.decrement}>-</button>
            <button onClick={props.hide}>hide</button>
            {props.show ? <p>hello world!</p> : null}
        </div>
    );
};

function mapStateToProps(state, show) {
return {
  count: state,
  //???
 };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return {
  increment: () => dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'}),
  decrement: () => dispatch({type: 'DECREMENT'}),
  hide: () => dispatch({type: 'HIDE'})
};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import App from './App.js'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const counter = (state = 0,  action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state = state + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return state= state - 1;
        case 'HIDE':
         //???
            // return show = true;
        default:
            return state;
  }
 };

const store = createStore(counter);

render(
  <Provider store={store} >
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
 );
```

Comment: You need a reducer, that reacts to the actions HIDE and SHOW. In `mapStateToProps` you select the properties you need in your class. e.g. `{hidden: state.app.hidden}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new reducer, but that is not required. What you can do is instead of maintaining `state=0`, have an object with two keys: `count and show`.

Like this:

```
const initialState = {
    count: 0,
    show: true,
}

const counter = (state = initialState,  action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {...state, count: state.count + 1};
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return {...state, count: state.count - 1};
        case 'HIDE':
            return {...state, show: false};
        case 'SHOW':
            return {...state, show: true}
        default:
            return state;
    } 
};
```

Now inside component, read `count` and `show` from store and pass them to component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        count: state.count,
        show: state.show
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to keep using `counter` reducer, first you need to change the default state from a single integer to an object with both properties (`counter` and `show`)

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  counter: 0,
  show: true,
}

const counter = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    default: return state
    case 'INCREMENT': 
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1,
      }
    case 'DECREMENT': 
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter - 1,
      }
    case 'HIDE': 
      return {
        ...state,
        show: false,
      }
  }
}
```

With that, now you need to change in your connected component from `props.count` to `props.count.counter` and `props.count.show` or simply map them in `mapStateToProps`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    count: state.counter,
    show: state.show,
 }
}
```

Comment: `mapStateToProps` doesn't need the second parameter `show`. That parameter is actually `ownProps`, or properties that are passed directly to the component from its parent in traditional React style, but it is not necessary. You can simply have `mapStateToProps(state)`

Comment: Right, I probably copied from his code and forgot to remove :)

Answer (score 1):

change your reducer to this

```
const counter = (state = {count : 0 , hide : false} ,  action) => 
{
    switch(action.type) 
    {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {...state , count : state.count + 1};
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return {...state , count : state.count - 1};
        case 'HIDE':
            return {...state , hide : true};
        case 'SHOW':
            return {...state , hide : false};
        default:
            return state;
    }
 };
```

in your component add show button and get state of count and hide

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.count}</p>
            <button onClick={props.increment}>+</button>
            <button onClick={props.decrement}>-</button>
            <button onClick={props.hide}>hide</button>
            <button onClick={props.show}>show</button>
            {!props.hide ? <p>hello world!</p> : null}
        </div>
    );
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        count: state.count,
        hide: state.hide
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
        decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }),
        hide: () => dispatch({ type: 'HIDE' }),
        show: () => dispatch({ type: 'SHOW' })
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```